# How to multiply rows from same column in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, formula

I have a list of data frames, I created an extra column in each dataframe in the list (dataframes in the list doesn´t have same number of observations) and would like to fill the extra column in each dataframe with the following formula:

one of the dataframes in the list (all dataframes have same variables but different number of observations)

```
   xA  xB  xC  xD   
   2   1   1   NA
   2   1   2   NA
   3   1   3   NA
   3   4   4   NA 
   5   5   5   NA
```

formula required

```
  xA  xB  xC  xD   
  2   1   1   2   ======>(1+xC1)=(1+1)=2
  2   1   2   6   ======>(1+xC1)*(1+xC2)=(1+1)*(1+2)=6
  3   1   3   24  ======>(1+xC1)*(1+xC2)*(1+xC3)=(1+1)*(1+2)*(1+3)=24
  3   4   4   120 ======>(1+xC1)*(1+xC2)*(1+xC3)*(1+xC4)=(1+1)*(1+2)*(1+3)*(1+4)=120
  5   5   5   720 ======>(1+xC1)*(1+xC2)*(1+xC3)*(1+xC4)*(1+xC5)=(1+1)*(1+2)*(1+3)*(1+4)*(1+5)=720
```

so what I am doing is multipling in the second row of xD the first and second row of xC, in the third row of xD the first second and third row of xC and so on.

Is there a way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: xC <- 1:5; unlist(slider::slide(xC, ~Reduce(.x + 1, f = "*"), .before = Inf))

Comment: Thank you  for your response, my question is I have different dataframes with different number of observations, so in this example is 1:5 but other dataframes have different lenght as part of a list. How can you apply the formula to different dataframes at once?

Comment: the formula should work for arbitrary length. Try assigning to xC, for example, 1:100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to achieve what you need using `slider` and `Reduce`.

```r
library(slider)

df <- data.frame(
  xA = c(2, 2, 3, 3,  5),
  xB = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 5),
  xC = 1:5,
  xD = rep(NA, 5)
)

df$xD <- unlist(slide(df$xC, ~Reduce(.x + 1, f = "*"), .before = Inf))

df
#>   xA xB xC  xD
#> 1  2  1  1   2
#> 2  2  1  2   6
#> 3  3  1  3  24
#> 4  3  4  4 120
#> 5  5  5  5 720
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`Slider` allows you to capture windows of your data.

```
slide(1:5,.f = ~.x, .before = Inf)
[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

`Reduce` lets you apply a function between all members of a vector. For example, if the vector is `c(1, 2, 3)` and the function is `*`, then it results in `1*2*3` = 6.

```
Reduce(f = "*", 1:5) # aka 1*2*3*4*5 = 120
[1] 120
```

Combining `slider` and `Reduce`, you can achieve what you need.